# DNS BIND zone transfer error: "failed to connect: host unreachable"

Tags: server, dns, bind, local, zone

I am setting up two local authoritative BIND DNS servers so that a client may communicate with virtual hosts on an apache server. One is the master (10.2.56.209) the other is the slave (10.2.56.186). I have the servers configured and they start, but I get this error in the log file on the slave when it tries to do the zone transfer from the master.

```
transfer of '2.10.in-addr.arpa/IN' from 10.2.56.209#53: failed to connect: host unreachable
transfer of '2.10.in-addr.arpa/IN' from 10.2.56.209#53: Transfer completed: 0     messages, 0 records, 0 bytes, 0.002 secs (0 bytes/sec)
```

**Slave's named.conf file**

```
options {
    listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };
    listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
    directory       "/var/named";
    dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
    statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
    memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
    allow-query     { any; };

    recursion no;
    allow-transfer { none; };

    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};
logging {
    channel default_debug {
            file "data/named.run";
            severity dynamic;
    };
};

zone "." IN {
    type hint;
    file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "cit.nku.edu" IN {
     type slave;
     file "cit.nku.edu";
     masters{10.2.56.209; };
};

zone "2.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
 type slave;
 file "2.10.in-addr.arpa";
 masters{10.2.56.209; };
};
```

**Master's named.conf file**

```
options {
        listen-on port 53 { 10.2.56.209; };
        listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
    recursion no;
    allow-transfer { none; };
    dnssec-enable yes;
    dnssec-validation yes;

    /* Path to ISC DLV key */
    bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

    managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

    pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
    session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
        channel default_debug {
                file "data/named.run";
                severity dynamic;
        };
};

zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "cit.nku.edu" IN {
  type master;
  file "cit.nku.edu";
  allow-transfer { 10.2.56.186; };
  notify yes;
};

# reverse zone

zone "2.10.in-addr.arpa" IN {
     type master;
     file "2.10.in-addr.arpa";
     allow-transfer {localhost; 10.2.56.186;};
     notify yes;
};
```

**forward zone file on the master**

```
$TTL    1H
@         IN   SOA   ns1.cit.nku.edu.  root.cit.nku.edu (
                   10 ; serial
                   1H ; refresh
                   15M ; retry
                   4W ; expire
                   1H ; Negative caching TTL of 1 hour
                   )
; Name servers
cit.nku.edu.  IN      NS     ns1.cit.nku.edu.
cit.nku.edu.  IN      NS     ns2.cit.nku.edu.
ns1           IN      A      10.2.56.209
ns2           IN      A      10.2.56.186
@             IN      A      10.2.62.33
www           IN      A      10.2.62.33
```

**reverse zone file**

```
$TTL 86400
$ORIGIN 2.10.IN-ADDR.ARPA.
@   IN  SOA     ns1.cit.nku.edu. root.cit.nku.edu. (
    10          ;Serial
    3600        ;refresh
    1800        ;retry
    604800      ;expire
    86400       ;minimum ttl
)
; Name Servers
        IN  NS          ns1.cit.nku.edu.
        IN  NS          ns2.cit.nku.edu.
        IN  PTR         cit.nku.edu.
209.56  IN  PTR         ns1.cit.nku.edu.
186.56  IN  PTR         ns2.cit.nku.edu.
33.62   IN  PTR         www.cit.nku.edu.
```

I can ping them between each other and dig the host names (ns1, ns2), but I cannot dig the ip addresses themselves. I have added the corresponding entries in the /etc/hosts and /etc/hostname files. I can provide other documents if needed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "host unreachable" here probably means that TCP port 53 is not open properly, as this is needed for `AXFR`. Try from slave: `dig @10.2.56.209 2.10.in-addr.arpa AXFR`. If that does not work then bind won't work either.

Comment: It said host unreachable for that command. Why is it not working andHow would I fix it? Patrick Mevzek

Comment: You have a network routing issue or a firewal filtering trafic between your two hosts. Only you can know why.